# user properties not set when executing command mvn jmeter:jmeter

Tags: jmeter-maven-plugin

Following is the relevent section of the pom file

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertiesUser>
                            <testData>test.csv</testData>
                            <threadNum>1</threadNum>
                            <rampUpPeriodSecs>5</rampUpPeriodSecs>
                            <loopCount>2</loopCount>
                        </propertiesUser>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <testFilesDirectory>test</testFilesDirectory>
                <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When i execute the command `mvn install`; all works fine the properties specified in `propertiesUser` element get set and work.

But when i execute `mvn jmeter:jmeter` none of user properties are set. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's a maven limitation, have a read of this:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Default+Plugin+Execution+IDs

It's also discussed here:

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/97

The problem is that Maven is ignoring everything within the execution block if you run the separate goals using the command line.

You could work around it by adding a GUI profile and a non-GUI profile and specifying your desired profile on the command line.  To do this you would need to add your plugin config into a profile in your POM (lets call it GUI) and then specify a profile on the command line e.g.

```
mvn verify -PGUI
```